# Getting data back into the root with nested components in vue

Tags: vue.js, frontend

I am building a multiple page app with latest Laravel and latest Vue.js. At the end of this post you will see what I am trying to achieve - which I have done visually. However the user needs to be able to edit the text, assigned user and the date of each item. I have started with the date and as you can see I have the date picker working as well.

[image]

Where I am struggling is updating the main model of data in the root so that I can save the changes that the user has made via a HTTP request. Initially the tree's data is loaded in via HTTP as well (example below).

I have built the below using nested components and I have read that two binding has been depreciated for props on components. I know that I need to emit and user events but I'm sure how this would work if the components are nested?

Here is an example of the data that get's loaded via HTTP. Below is a very small example, however this could be much larger

```
{
    "objective":"Test",
    "user_id":null,
    "by":"08\/09\/2018",
    "colour":"#1997c6",
    "children":[
        {
            "objective":"Test",
            "user_id":11,
            "by":"08\/09\/2018",
            "colour":"#d7e3bc",
            "children":[]
        }, {
            "objective":"Test",
            "user_id":11,
            "by":null,
            "colour":"#1997c6",
            "children":[]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are the components that I have put together so far.

```
Vue.component('tree-date', {
    props: ['date'],

    data () {
        return {
            id: 0
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.id = uniqueId();

        $('#picker-' + this.id).datetimepicker({
             format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
             ignoreReadonly: true
        });
    },

    template: `
    <div class="date-container" :id="'picker-' + id" data-target-input="nearest" data-toggle="datetimepicker" :data-target="'#picker-' + id">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" readonly="readonly" :data-target="'#picker-' + id" v-model="date">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
});


Vue.component('tree-section', {
    props: ['data', 'teamUsers', 'first'],

    methods: {
        test () {
            this.$emit('test');
        }
    },

    template: `
        <table v-if="data.length != 0">
            <tr>
                <td :colspan="data.children !== undefined && (data.children.length * 2) > 0 ? data.children.length * 2 : 2">
                    <div class="node" :class="{'first': first == true}">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <tree-date :date="data.by"></tree-date>

                            <div class="objective">
                                {{ data.objective }}
                            </div>

                            <div class="author" v-if="data.user_id !== null">
                                {{ teamUsers[data.user_id].first_name }} {{ teamUsers[data.user_id].last_name }}
                            </div>

                            <div class="author" v-if="data.user_id === null">
                                Unassigned
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="lines" v-if="data.children.length > 0">
                <td :colspan="data.children.length * 2"><div class="downLine"></div></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="lines" v-if="data.children.length > 0">
                <td class="rightLine"></td>

                <td class="topLine" v-for="index in ((data.children.length * 2) - 2)" :key="index" :class="{'rightLine': index % 2 == 0, 'leftLine':  Math.abs(index % 2) == 1}"></td>

                <td class="leftLine"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr v-if="data.children.length > 0">
                <td colspan="2" v-for="child in data.children">
                    <tree-section :data="child" :team-users="teamUsers" :first="false"></tree-section>                
                </td>            
            </tr>
        </table>
    `
});
```

This all get's called in the view by:

```
<tree-section :data="data" :team-users="teamUsers" :first="true"></tree-section>
```

Any help getting data update in the components back into the root will be most helpful.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Vuex. If I understand your post correctly, it's a perfect fit for your use case.

Comment: @StephenThomas Thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, vue props (if objects or arrays) are being passed by reference- that means that if you change your object on the child component, the original object on the parent component will get changed too.
from vue api:

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so
> if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself
> inside the child component will affect parent state.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: Oh man... you're complete right! It didn't look like it was working on my app but this appears to be an issue with datepicker! Just tested editing the text and works fine!

Comment: glad i could help.